# What are the practical differences between installing LaTeX from MacTeX or MacPorts/Homebrew?

Tags: installing, mactex, macports

When I started using a unix based system it was very natural to install MacTeX, since the installation of it is more "windows-like", though the installation package is *huge*. Later I was introduced to MacPorts, and recently Homebrew, which also provide easy ways of installing LaTeX on my system. However, I find myself unable to distinguish the practical differences between these alternatives and argument for using one or the other.

1. Does MacTeX, MacPorts and Homebrew provide different versions of LaTeX?
2. Downloading and maintaining tex-libraries with MacTeX is quite easy and automatized through the TexLive utility. Are there similar solutions if one choose to install LaTeX with MacPorts or Homebrew?
3. Are there advantages/disadvantages with using one or the other solution?

Comment: I haven't used `homebrew` but most linux-like package managers are not ideal for installing and updating a TeX distribution because of a fundamental misunderstanding about what a TeX "package" is.  See [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX install](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50470/2693) for some discussion.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

It is possible to install MacTeX with homebrew using [Homebrew Cask](https://formulae.brew.sh/cask/) via

```
$ brew install --cask mactex
```

Since that basically downloads the MacTeX.pkg from ctan it should not be different from the usual manual installation.

If you would like to install without the GUI, you can

```
$ brew install --cask mactex-no-gui
```

Comment: The only benefit here is remembering that you have it installed on your system, and having an easy, one-command way of uninstalling it again later: `brew cask uninstall mactex`.

Comment: (The `basictex` package is also available.)

Comment: `basictex` doesn't contain morderncv for instance

Answer (score 47):

1. Homebrew does not provide any version of LaTeX:

   ```
   $ brew search latex
   latex-mk     latex2html   latex2rtf    pplatex      rtf2latex2e

   If you meant `latex' precisely:

   Installing TeX from source is weird and gross, requires a lot of patches,
   and only builds 32-bit (and thus can't use Homebrew deps on Snow Leopard.)

   We recommend using a MacTeX distribution: http://www.tug.org/mactex/
   ```

   Macports' texlive port and MacTeX are both based on the latest TeXlive distribution, MacTeX is very complete (https://www.tug.org/mactex/whatsinthepackage.html) whereas you have much more granularity with all the texlive-* ports of macports (https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=texlive).
2. With macports, all the above mentioned packages can be installed/updated through the usual `port install` and `port update` commands. However, if you need a package that **is not pre-packaged by macports** then you get absolutely no help (but I doubt that there are many).
3. I used to use the macport-based texlive distribution, since it allowed me to avoid downloading stuff I didn't need (BibDesk or Excalibur for instance). Now I'm using homebrew and MacTeX, which is better integrated with MacOS X in general (fonts for instance). Disk-space (bandwidth) vs. integration.

Basically both are good solutions so it mostly depends on what else you do… I switched from macports to homebrew for reasons not at all related to TeX, hence my switch in TeX providers.

Comment: With respect to the reasoning behind Homebrew dropping its `tex-live` formula, read https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/1087

Comment: This post is no longer accurate. `brew uninstall --force brew-cask; brew update; brew cask install Caskroom/cask/mactex`

Comment: Update 2020: `brew cask install mactex` is what the search command tells you to do now.

Answer (score 19):

I just installed MacTeX with homebrew.

```
brew install --cask mactex
```

That provided me with /Application/TeX, containing TeXShop program and the utilities.

However, I am missing the pdflatex tool from command line, and that also produces errors in the TeXShop program:

[image]

After searching a little bit around, [I found out that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274806/pdflatex-file-missing-after-upgrade) the missing utilities were actually bundled with MacTeX, and located in `Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin`.

Great! I will just create a symbolic link to from that location to `/usr/texbin`. Turns out that I cannot (even with root), create files in /usr on a modern Macintosh (since El Capitan), because of the [System Integrity Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Integrity_Protection). I considered disabling it with `csrutil`, but choose rather to try to symlink the required binaries into /usr/local/bin.

```
ln -s /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin/pdflatex /usr/local/bin
```

Did the trick for me.

<sub><sup><sub><sup>*note I found a issue in the brew/caskroom repo that might be related.
https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask/issues/20592
Feel free to update this answer if it gets fixed</sup></sub></sup></sub>

Comment: If you want to use TeXShop, just change the Path Settings under Engine in Preferences to `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

Comment: just to note: as of 2021, the proper syntax is now: `brew install --cask mactex`

Answer (score 7):

I installed LaTeX with MacPorts as an experiment. It seems to be working really well. I installed the main packages with:

```
sudo port install texlive texlive-latex-extra
```

which got most of it and took around 15 minutes.

I like to use TeXShop so I installed that as well:

```
sudo port install texshop3
```

which requires some reconfiguration to work with the MacPorts LaTeX.  In its preferences, in the Engine tab I change the path for both (pdf)TeX and Distiller (ghostscript) to `/opt/local/bin`. In the Misc tab I changed the names of the Tex and Latex programs to `xetex` and `xelatex` respectively.

(I also changed the default encoding to UTF-8).

**2021 Update:** These days, I use `brew`, following the instructions in the [answer above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155081/125101).

Answer (score 6):

Talking about MacPorts:

> 3. Are there advantages/disadvantages with using one or the other solution?

#### Advantage of MacPorts

Its latex integrates better & easier with other MacPorts packages.
Especially, if you already use MacPorts, sticking to the MacPorts package makes it easy to maintain your ecosystem (like upgrading / uninstalling dependencies).

Moreover, you can save a lot of disk space by having more fine-grained control over which TeX packages you install. Homebrew-Cask just grabs the whole `mactex` distribution which can consume ~15GB on disk. With Macports on the other hand, you can consume less than 1GB or just a few GB depending on what you install. It's certainly more lightweight.

#### Disadvantage of MacPorts

On the other hand, a disadvantage is that some apps cannot find the latex software suit, as @Manuel commented.

> I've got errors (something works from terminal, but not from TeXWorks, TeXShop, TextMate, …)

To overcome this, you need to set the (la)tex paths manually. Some apps let you set paths in Settings menu, while for others you may put the correct paths in `~/.profile` and launch the apps from Terminal.app.

Another problem, as @Alan mentioned, is that managing packages absent in MacPorts is tricky. I'd install these extra packages inside my user directory to keep them separate from MacPorts.

Comment: I could put more information on advantages and disadvantages of MacTex / MacPorts (or Homebrew) if someone thinks its worth.