# pdflatex file missing after upgrade

Tags: mactex, mac

My documents won't compile after upgrading to El Capitan on MacTex, and I saw that this usually means that the upgrade changed the path to pdflatex. However, it looks like the file is no longer on my mac anywhere. However, in Library/bin/TeX there are a bunch of similarly named files like pdfplatex, pdfplatex2, pdfuplatex, etc. Is it possible it got renamed somehow, or do I just have to reinstall the whole distribution to get the file back?

Comment: Please look up all the other questions on the site about El Capitan. Apple made a change so the shortcut editors on Mac use to refer to the location of the latex binaries, no longer work. You usually just need to make a small reconfiguration of your editor (if you are using mactex 2015). It is well documented in other posts on the site

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to add /Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin to the $PATH in ~/.bashrc

export PATH=.:/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH