# MacTex successfully installed but unable to launch

Tags: mac, mactex

I have successfully Installed mactex using brew as shown below

```
  $ brew cask install mactex
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20170524.pkg
Already downloaded: /Users/amar/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Cask/mactex--20170524
.pkg
==> Verifying checksum for Cask mactex
==> Installing Cask mactex
==> Running installer for mactex; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are 
Password:
==> installer: Package name is MacTeX-2017
==> installer: Installing at base path /
==> installer: The install was successful.
  mactex was successfully installed!
```

The issue is that how do I launch it now. I am not able to find it in applications or using search `(command + space)`

[image]

Comment: start TeXShop as Editor

Comment: I still have the same issue, I even I open TexShop I cant see GUI for MacTex

Comment: You should start `TeXShop`  and _not_ MAcTeX. Then write your document and run it.

Comment: Perhaps this question [What TeX software to write technical papers with?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/66470) will give you an overview of how everything fits together. MacTeX is a whole set of programs/scripts that work together. It is not a single piece of software, and if you are a beginner it's best to interact with it via an editor like TeXShop.  There is lots of good information in the TeXShop Help menu to get you started.

Comment: Also [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11).

Comment: I’m not familiar with that way of installing MacTeX; it has its own installer. I wonder if that method installs the TeX distribution structures and symbolic links that MacTeX installer does so everything works out of the box.

Comment: @HerbSchulz `homebrew` simply downloads the MacTeX installer and runs it in this case, so you end up with a regular MacTeX installation.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still confused, the GUIs installed with homebrew can be found in the `/Applications/TeX` folder. Searching `TeX` with `Cmd + [Space]` will not find the nested programs by default.

Source: [What Is Installed? (Section 3 GUI Applications)](https://www.tug.org/mactex/What_Is_Installed.pdf)

Comment: I think the confusion on the original question was that the OP thought that MacTeX installs a GUI Application that *is* TeX, but this is simply not the case.

Comment: Understood, I agree that the distinction is important. However there is still the follow-up question of "How do I launch the GUI?" so my answer is meant to address that specifically. Currently the standard way of installing TeX using brew is to run the command `brew install --cask mactex`, which includes several GUIs as part of the package. From my understanding, the older command `brew cask install mactex` also includes GUIs: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155081/240361