# Is there a dropin replacement for brew install pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to make use of a project that is no longer maintained that relies on pdflatex. However,

```
% brew install pdflatex
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
######################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/cask.jws.json
######################################################################################################################################################################### 100.0%
Warning: No available formula with the name "pdflatex". Did you mean pdf2htmlex?
==> Searching for similarly named formulae and casks...
==> Formulae
pdf2htmlex

To install pdf2htmlex, run:
  brew install pdf2htmlex
% brew install pdf2htmlex
Error: pdf2htmlex has been disabled because it has an archived upstream repository!
```

Is there a dropin replacement for pdflatex that I could use to get this program that depends on it to run?

Comment: `pdflatex` is very much alive and well, but rarely (if ever) packaged by itself. You want a TeX distribution which will provide it instead. MacTeX fits the bill and [is available through brew](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155081/106162).