# How to uninstall TeX Live on Mac which is installed through command "sudo port install texlive +full"?

Tags: installing, emacs, auctex, mac, ptex

At the beginning, my purpose is to set up AUCTeX with Emacs. I just do like below

1. Download [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/), then `cd` to the directory, `make` and `sudo make install`.
2. It works well when the `.tex` file only contains english characters. But when I create a `.tex` with Japanese characters and enter command `C-c C-c`. It will prompt error message

`LaTeX Error: This file needs format 'pLaTeX2e' but this is 'LaTeX2e'`

I search on google and find It is because LaTex2e don't support Japanese characters. I should install **pLaTeX2e** as well. At last I found command

```
$ sudo port install texlive +full
```

on the site http://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/~okumura/texwiki/?Mac#f8cc2ba3. 
It is really a horrible command; it uses almost 7GB storage but the issue is still not resolved.

Anyone who has any suggestion to delete this file completely or resolve this error issue?

Comment: First I don't think it has anything to do with `AUCTeX` nor with `emacs`. Secondly, did you try `sudo port uninstall texlive`?

Comment: still not, I'm afraid This command will not remove file completely, so I think it will be better to ask first.

Comment: In terms of removing this installation, I think this is the way to go. Maybe you would like to run `sudo port uninstall --follow-dependencies`. See `port help uninstall` for help.

Comment: I think Macports is pretty good about placing everything inside `/opt`, so (worst case scenario) you could start again from scratch if all else fails.  There is also a `MacTeX.pkg` that is 2.3GB that you could download and install without using Macports:  http://tug.org/mactex/

Comment: Continuing from what @lawlist suggested, MacTeX is probably the easiest option here, along with [GNU Emacs compiled for OSX](http://emacsformacosx.com).  You can install AUCTeX from within Emacs via `M-x list-packages`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer based on the comments.

As others have noted, this problem isn't really about Emacs or AucTeX, but about your TeX Distribution. And here, the problem is MacPorts. The *de facto* standard Mac distribution is the MacTeX distribution.  You should generally avoid other types of package manager versions of TeX Live.  See [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX installation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/50470/2693) for some discussion of why.

To remove a MacPorts port, you need to use

```
sudo port uninstall --follow-dependents <portname>
```

So use this to uninstall the TeX port you added.

Then do a fresh install of [MacTeX](https://tug.org/mactex/).

This will set your TeX binary directory to `/usr/texbin`.

For a MacOS version of `emacs` see: [this link](http://emacsformacosx.com/), or use [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/).