# Suggestion of LaTeX Complete Package?

Tags: editors

I would like to use LaTeX system to do my assignments as I am starting graduate program in applied mathematics.

Please can you suggest me good typesetting package system that would help create documents quicker. I see plenty of options [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_TeX_editors) and would like some advice on which one to pick. I am a newbie.

Comment: This question would solicit "primarily opinion-based answers", and is therefore not really a good fit. Some would prefer editor X while others would prefer editor Y. You should read [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764) and make up your own mind as to the offerings of each.

Comment: Note that editors are separate from a TeX system, where the choice is on Windows between TeX Live and MiKTeX, and on other systems really just TeX Live (in the MacTeX 'wrapper' on the Mac).

Comment: I suggest to have a look at [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/)

Comment: You might also have a look at http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ehm I think a note on the very basics could be useful here.

LaTeX (actually a macro-package for TeX) is *just* a typesetting engine (compare it eg. with html). It makes nothing more than taking you plain-text file and convert it to something. So basically, your setting consists of three components:

- The LaTeX-bundle (like TeX Live or MiKTeX) with the compilers eg. `latex`, `pdftex`, ...
- the plain-text editor of your desire and
- Display engine like Evince, Zathura, Adobe Reader, ...

That makes the basic workflow:

1. Write your plain code
2. Compile it (`pdflatex` compiles to *pdf*, `latex` compiles to *dvi*, ...)
3. Watch it

Therefore you can take any editor you like. This is a highly subjective decision you have to make yourself.

Editors often taken by beginners are Texmaker, Kile or LyX. Some more advanced and highly configurable editors are Vim and Emacs.

I prefer using Vim but this would be a steep learning curve. :-)

---

Edit: For some literature, have a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-is-the-best-book-to-start-learning-latex).

Answer (score -1):

If you use Ubuntu, I hope you do.

```
sudo apt-get install latexila texlive-full
```

It's a complete package of LaTeX.

If you want something more easily

```
sudo apt-get install lyx
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. If I install complete latex package, would I still require lyx?

Comment: Latex package is just it, you need an editor. Latexila or lyx.

Comment: That is, you will need LaTeX either way.  I would take a look at the linked list of editors; I personally vouch for Emacs/AUCTeX.  (It's even good for beginners! I've personally seen it be a good thing. Takes some time though.)

Comment: There are good reasons *not* to install the TeX via the Linux package manager.  See [Adding a CTAN package to a MacPorts-maintained TeX installation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/50502) for some reasons why (the specific answer deals with Mac, but is applicable to all Linux systems too) and  [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092) for how to install TeX Live without using the prepackaged versions.

Comment: And don't install it with admin/root privileges...